# 500 Error on Codeigniter/PHP uploads > ~100MB

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, upload

Seems like a question that has been answered countless times.

My php.ini should allow it. My .htaccess also ought to be supporting it. I have, in the past and in some older answered posts, seen that if I copy php.ini into working directories of the scripts, it will resolve. No dice.

I have also made a new configuration file in CodeIgniter's system config folder to allow for large uploads, larger than I'm trying. The limit in MB could be arbitrary, I'm guessing it could also be a thread/process time limit but I set that to be pretty high for testing this as well.

I have restarted apache2. Still no luck. I'm on AWS services with an EC2, ElasticBeanstalk, and S3.

Comment: general rule for 500: if you get one, you go look at the server's error log FIRST. anything else is just randomly stabbing around in the dark.

Comment: You don't get a 500 error if the file is too large. There is something else wrong. Do as @MarcB suggests, check the error log, or turn display errors on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a batchsize argument in Amazon SDK for their S3 servers. This was fixed after making changes to an API file and allowing the server to restart and browsers to stop using old cache.

Thanks for the help and I've enabled error logging, unfortunately the ex-dev had it turned off and I didn't think to check before I ran into problems with the setup.

Answer (score 0):

Are u using .htaccess? Check his settings.
This is my gist file for setup lamp: https://gist.github.com/landsman/6127c9a22aa8c5ba59b8c2285c30a768